# How to get error codes while Firebase Admin SDK throwing errors in Python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I try to create an account in firebase, here is my code

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth

try:
    user = auth.create_user(email=email, password=password)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

while error occurs, for example, password is too short, I got an exception of ValueError. It's not easy to handle at all.

There is [a list of Admin Authentication API Errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors) in the Firebase guides. it would be perfect if I can retrieve the error pack as following,

```
{
'code' : 'auth/invalid-password',
'message' : 'The provided value for the password user property is invalid. It must be a string with at least six characters.'
}
```

I ever got those messages via javascript. However, I couldn't find a clue for python platform. Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Invalid method arguments (like too short password) trigger [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) in Python SDK. This is natural in Python, and the behavior is documented in Admin SDK API docs -- see the "Raises" section of the [`create_user()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#create_user) method. There are no error codes associated with this type of errors. These are essentially precondition failures. The best way to deal with them is to sanitize the inputs before calling the method, and handling erroneous inputs in the user code.

In Python Admin SDK error codes are only available through [`auth.AuthError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#autherror). These are raised only when a call to a backend server fails.